# How to open multiple files in one window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making an mp3 player in C# WPF and I'm having trouble opening several files through explorer. The fact is that when you open several files through the Explorer context menu, each song opens in a separate program, I want that if the player is already open, when you reopen the application, a new song is transferred to the open application, and not played in a new one, how can this be implemented?

(Sorry for my bad english)

```cs
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Args.Length != 0)
    {
        var path = e.Args[0];
        Player.PlaySong(new Song(path));
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time of meditation, I managed to reach a solution with a TcpListener & TcpClient.

Here's the code, if someone comes in handy (checking for an open copy of the application, data transfer, etc. can be changed, such methods work for me).

Startup:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName");
if (processes.Length > 1)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 12000));

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    sw.WriteLine($"addsong:{path}");

    client.Close();

    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
else
{
    var thread = new Thread(ListenerCallback);
    thread.Start();
}
```

---

Tcp Listener thread:

```
private void ListenerCallback()
{  
    TcpListener listner = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 12000));
    listner.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = listner.AcceptTcpClient();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        MessageBox.Show($"Recieved data: {sr.ReadLine()}");
        client.Close();

        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```